# Unix - Compare two files and align them line by line

Tags: bash, unix

I have two files:
The first has all the sequence names like this:

```
comp10604_c0_seq1
comp108_c0_seq1
comp11450_c0_seq1
comp11655_c0_seq1
comp11804_c0_seq1
comp13465_c0_seq1
comp13695_c0_seq1
```

The second has information concerning these sequences but it lacks information on certain sequences like this:

```
comp10604_c0_seq1 AB491617.1
comp11450_c0_seq1 AM920464.1
comp11655_c0_seq1 HQ865168.1
comp11804_c0_seq1 KC900889.1
comp13465_c0_seq1 HM590421.1
comp13695_c0_seq1 GU474930.1
```

I would like a file where replace a line break and insert the name of the sequence if there is no information the sequence like this:

```
comp10604_c0_seq1 AB491617.1
comp108_c0_seq1 NAN
comp11450_c0_seq1 AM920464.1
comp11655_c0_seq1 HQ865168.1
comp11804_c0_seq1 KC900889.1
comp13465_c0_seq1 HM590421.1
comp13695_c0_seq1 GU474930.1
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your input appears sorted.  You could use `join`; specify the value for the missing fields:

```
join -e "NaN" -a1 -a2 -o 1.1 2.2 first second
```

For your sample input, it'd produce:

```
comp10604_c0_seq1 AB491617.1
comp108_c0_seq1 NaN
comp11450_c0_seq1 AM920464.1
comp11655_c0_seq1 HQ865168.1
comp11804_c0_seq1 KC900889.1
comp13465_c0_seq1 HM590421.1
comp13695_c0_seq1 GU474930.1
```

Pipe the output to `column -t` if you prefer it to be aligned.

Comment: And if I have several columns in informations files that I would like to join in the same time ?

Comment: @muramasa join 2 files at a time, pipe the result to another join which takes the STDOUT of previous join as an input and the third file as another input.  Please refer to `info join` for more.

Answer (score 1):

If your file is sorted and you wish to compare just one column, then [devnull](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23722428/970195) has the right answer.

Here is another way using `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{seq[$1]=$2;next}{print $1,($1 in seq?seq[$1]:"NaN")}' file2 file1
comp10604_c0_seq1 AB491617.1
comp108_c0_seq1 NaN
comp11450_c0_seq1 AM920464.1
comp11655_c0_seq1 HQ865168.1
comp11804_c0_seq1 KC900889.1
comp13465_c0_seq1 HM590421.1
comp13695_c0_seq1 GU474930.1
```

We iterate over file2 first storing column2 as value to an array indexed at column1. For the file1, we print column 1 and check if the key exists in our array. If so, we print the value next to it else we print `NaN`.